# pkg-config: include paths for C and C++

Tags: gcc, autotools, autoconf, automake, pkg-config

Is it possible to specify include paths for C and C++ in a pkg-config file (`mylib.pc.in`)?

I know I have `Cflags` field where I can pass any *compiler* flags, but it is generic and `autoconf` resolves it  by placing all my options, as long as the include paths in `X_CFLAGS` but not `X_CXXFLAGS`.

So if I have a project that contains both C and C++ files and specify in `Makefile.am`:

```
mybin_CPPFLAGS = $(X_CPPFLAGS)
mybin_CFLAGS     = $(X_CFLAGS)
mybin_CXXFLAGS = $(X_CXXFLAGS)
```

My C++ files can't see the include path!
In the example bellow, `mylib.pc.in` contains `Cflags: -I/my/iclude/path/`.

Output compiling a C file:

```
libtool: compile:  ppc-linux-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/usr/include/ -I/my/iclude/path/ -Wall -std=gnu99 -MT libAW3C_IDU_la-aw3c_utility.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libAW3C_IDU_la-aw3c_utility.Tpo -c src/aw3c_utility.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libAW3C_IDU_la-aw3c_utility.o
```

Output compiling a C++ file (notice the missing `-I/my/iclude/path/`):

```
libtool: compile:  ppc-linux-g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/usr/include/ -Wall -MT libAW3C_IDU_la-aw3c_stream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libAW3C_IDU_la-aw3c_stream.Tpo -c src/aw3c_stream.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libAW3C_IDU_la-aw3c_stream.o
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pkg-config` has the option `--cflags-only-I` that only yields the include paths in `Cflags`. So you can add something like:

```
X_INCFLAGS=`pkg-config mylib --cflags-only-I`
X_CXXFLAGS+="$X_INCFLAGS"
```

to `configure.ac`. Q: Are you using the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro in `configure.ac`?

Comment: Yes, I am using PKG_CHECK_MODULES. Does it give me anything plus (or less)? Thanks!